# Any ideas on why my computer is giving me desync?

Tags: networking, windows-10

I play Minecraft and I have constant slight desync. I can have 10 computers on the same router and mine would be the only one with desync. My Laptop is a Lenovo Z70 gaming computer. How might I test to see what program is causing this? It's been making me super mad for like 2 years now and I now know it is definitely on my computer's side.

Comment: Are you using Ethernet or wireless?

Comment: which firewall, antivirus and antimalware programs do you use? if using wireless, is it 2g or 5g, and what is the signal strength? what is your ping time to the server?

Comment: Wireless. I have firewall disabled, and I use windows defender and scan every now and then. I work in IT so I look for viruses and check out downloads myself.